# How to Manage AppSettings by Build Configuration name not Environment?

Tags: c#, .net

Currently, we use the `BUILD CONFIGURATION` from the `Configuration Manager` to drive `web.config` and `app.config` configuration-transformation in our builds.

For example
[image: BUILD CONFIGURATION NAMES]

We are in the midst of upgrading to .NET Core & a lot of examples show the use of `Environment Variables` to drive configuration-transformation in `appsettings.json`.  But I can't seem to find examples that correctly transform the `appsettings.json` file using BUILD CONFIGURATION.

Q: Is it even possible to let the BUILD CONFIGURATION transform the `appsettings.json` file anymore?
Q: If so...how?

I am super not interested in going into 100+ servers & setting an environment variable in IIS.

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
                        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        {
                            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment; //<-- I dont want to do this

                            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
                        })
                        .UseServiceProviderFactory<ServiceRegistry>(new LamarServiceProviderFactory())
                        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                        {
                            var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString(JsonSettings.ConnectionStrings.WorkflowComponentDb);

                            services.AddLamar(new ContainerRegistry());
                            services.AddDbContext<IntegrationDbContext>((provider, options) => { options.UseSqlServer(connectionString); });
                            services.AddOptions();
                        })
                        .UseConsoleLifetime();
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: How are you deploying your apps? Do you have some automation scripts? For local development you can specify any configuration in launchSettings.json

Comment: ATM...I'm experimenting by playing the application through VS 2022.  Is "launchSettings.json" the way to go?  And, does it work with BUILD CONFIGURATION?  If so, please feel free to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as it turns out some folks were VERY close...but here is the answer:

1. You must apply "Copy Always" to all variations of the "appsettings.{BuildName}.json" files.
2. Retrieve the current build-configuration (name) using the executing assembly
3. Apply the concatenation as below

Why is this favorable? (to me)
I don't have to change my existing Azure DevOps pipelines.
I don't need to register ENVIRONMENTAL variables on machines.
I don't need to worry about "competing builds" on build servers.
I don't have to dedicate build servers to specific ENVIRONMENTAL variables.
I don't need to create "launch setting" files.

...all of which seem bloated & over-complicated (to me)

THAT SAID:
If you can see a reason why ENVIRONMENTAL variables are better (than this)...I would be interested in your thoughts.  It just seems like "too many moving parts" (to me).

```
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder()
                        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
                        {
                            var assemblyConfigurationAttribute = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyConfigurationAttribute>();
                            var buildConfiguration = assemblyConfigurationAttribute?.Configuration;

                            switch (buildConfiguration)
                            {
                                case "Development":
                                case "ModelOffice":
                                case "Production":
                                case "Release":
                                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{buildConfiguration}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        .UseServiceProviderFactory<ServiceRegistry>(new LamarServiceProviderFactory())
                        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                        {
                            var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString(JsonSettings.ConnectionStrings.WorkflowComponentDb);

                            services.AddLamar(new ContainerRegistry());
                            services.AddDbContext<IntegrationDbContext>((provider, options) => { options.UseSqlServer(connectionString); });
                        })
                        .UseConsoleLifetime();
    return builder;
}
```

Comment: If someone wants the credit because they feel their answer was close...let me know.  And...I will edit their answer with this text & mark it as correct.

Comment: With this approach you will have equal or more number of changes just to introduce a hack. which will probably cause you some problems further. For example, you may need to have logic dependent on the environment in which the code is executing. Easily done with built in environment variables, while with this approach you will have to build further on this hack. Cheers!

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the note. That said...IMHO...this is not a hack. Why? Your business/execution layer should NEVER-to-RARELY have logic that depends on the environment. The ONLY "execution items" that should change based on environment is settings.

Comment: The only exception should be "some" pre-processor items...and they should be EXTREMELY rare. In fact, I would venture to say, if someone depends on their environment to manage logic...they have probably taken a wrong-turn somewhere in their code. Thanks again.

Comment: Think about email service that should not execute anywhere except in production, or at emails routed at internal email. Or features that are not yet complete, or not completely tested so they mustn't be enabled yet in production, only in dev environments. Maybe you want to use different db in dev vs prod. Stuff like that.

Comment: Howdy!  Unfinished features are easily remedied by not publishing their access-points or not instantiating their providers (until ready).  All environments should "mirror" one-another...otherwise you cannot guarantee faithful promotion across environments.  Thanks again.

Comment: SIDE NOTE: I do often create a build configuration called LOCAL (used locally by the dev) for email services wherein I send emails to localhost port (I use SMTP4DEV locally) .  All other environment run as-normal.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to define a different compilation symbol for each configuration and use that to `#if X` set the environment name.

Please see [Set the environment in code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-the-environment-in-code).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create some appsetting.json based on your build names like:

- appsetting.Debug.json
- appsetting.Release.json
- appsetting.Local.json
- so on ...

So there are two ways to handle the settings:

- 1- Old way

```cs
 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
#if Local
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Local.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
#elif ModelOffice
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.ModelOffice.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
//add another files
#endif
;
```

- 2- Use the `Configuration` name and `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`

First you need to create a configuration based on the build name like this:

[image]

And in the `launchSetting.json` file use this:

```json
  "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "$(Configuration)"
      }
```

And finally in the program.cs

```cs
 config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
```

Answer (score 1):

For local development, in the [launchSettings.json file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson), you can create any configurations you like, and then launch them using VS by selecting one of them in the Start button dropdown list. This way the environment variables are read from this file behind the scenes when you run the application.

For production I asked how are you deploying the app, since if you have some automation scripts you can [set the environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-environment-on-the-command-line) in those scripts, in the part where you run/release the app, something like

```
dotnet run --environment Production
```

Apparently there's also some possibility to [set it in web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0#windows---use-webconfig) file, this may be most useful for you but I have not used it myself.

Last thing I want to mention is that the runtime will read `appsettings.json` file plus `appsettings.<YOUR_ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT_VALUE>.json` and will override any overlapping settings from appsettings.json file with those. This is done behind the scenes and you don't have to read those files manually in the app via code, like in some other answers in this post (you still need to add them manually into the project).

Comment: Thanks for the answering.  We're using Azure DevOps.  Everything is currently setup to use "Build Configuration"...and I don't want to change the pipelines for 50+ applications

Comment: You probably have a common step/script then for all of those 50 apps. There should be an easy way.